# needs to find \t in the middle of a string

Tags: python, json, regex

I have a json file with two variables:

```
\t\t"ROW_ID" : 475895,

\t\t"TEXT" : "TITLE:\tCardiology Consult\n\t24 Hour Events:\n\tPatient without any further...
```

I need to find the tabs (`\t`) in the middle of `TEXT` (because I cannot load this into python correctly), not the ones at the beginning of the lines, so I can remove them. I am having trouble because there are two tabs at the beginning of the lines, so `.\t` does not work. Using notepad++. Any ideas?

Comment: Would the usual answer not be either: "Take another JSON parser" or "\t is illegal inside a json string"? :) Not sure which of both is closer to the mark, as I usually avoid using JSON...

Comment: Post some example code, how are you trying to load this in python? I'd expect json.loads() to handle it just fine.

Comment: Are those supposed to be tabs in the middle of the string? Because you've marked them with "\n", not "\t".

Comment: Try `\t+(?=")`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. With a negative lookbehind, you can make sure you're not unnecessarily removing the tabs that come right after newlines.

```
(?<!\n)\t+
```

If you're worried that `\n` will match the character `n` instead of a newline on some regex engines, use `\x0A` instead.

```
(?<!\x0A)\t+
```